# Show two fields in Wicket DropDownChoice via ChoiceRenderer

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.6, dropdownchoice

In my `DropDownChoice` I want to show two fields: Name - Surname

```
DropDownChoice<Person> customer = new DropDownChoice<Person>(
                    "customer", new PropertyModel<Person>(customermodel, "customer"),list, new ChoiceRenderer<Person>("name", "id"));
```

How I can do that? Like: **Peter - Griffin**

Answer (score 5):

You can just override `getDisplayValue(Person object)` method for `ChoiceRender` like this:

```java
new ChoiceRenderer<Person>("name", "id")
{
    @Override
    public Object getDisplayValue(Person object)
    {
        //insert your logic for checking super.method emptiness and etc here.
        return super.getDisplayValue(object) + "-" + object.getSurname();
    }
}
```

Or just implement your own `IChoiceRenderer`interface.